# Scheduling a build using Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubectl

The doc https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html provides details of creating a cron job.

To start a scheduled task that executes a build every 10 mins I use the command:

```
oc run run-build 161/my-app --image=myimage --restart=OnFailure --schedule='*/10 * * * *'
```

Which returns:

```
cronjob.batch/run-build created
```

But the job fails to start:

The log of pod displays:

```
Error: unknown command "161/my-app" for "openshift-deploy"
Run 'openshift-deploy --help' for usage.
```

Have I configured the command ( `oc run run-build 161/my-app --image=myimage --restart=OnFailure --schedule='*/10 * * * *'` ) to start the cron job incorrectly ?

Comment: What is the `command` that your job needs to run?

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation you're giving, you need to remove `run-build` from the command :

```
$ oc run NAME --image=<image> \
    [--generator=<resource>] \
    [--port=<port>] \
    [--replicas=<replicas>] \
    [--dry-run=<bool>] \
    [--overrides=<inline_json>] \
    [options]
```